# Validating an email address with AWS Auth JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, validation

I am trying to validate an email address without using any front end validation through my react native app. I am hoping i can send the email through the AWS Auth API and get a valid or invalid response? Does anyone know the method for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? However, is username attribute is email then call Auth.signUp(values) and AWS will throw some error on your face saying that it's not a valid email

Comment: Hi Zohib, 

I have a modal which pops up for forgot password, but while retrieving the email address i need to validate it. I don't want to use javascript to validate it when i'm sure i can use aws auth to check that i meets the requirements of my user pool. Any other information? Thanks.

Comment: Ath.forgotPassword(usernameEmail) will retrun a promise and it will either be resolved if email exists in userpool otherwise it will be rejected with some error which you can show to the user

Comment: Hi Zohaib,

Please see below and let me know if you have any solution. Thanks.

Comment: @DontCodeMelmScared It's strange that you have integrated `aws-amplify` sdk but you are reluctant to add some javascript for field validation.

Comment: Hey Zohaib, i guess ill do it that way! Thanks